# Eclipse for PHP suggests me variables even if I just press space

Tags: php, eclipse, autosuggest

I'm using Eclipse Luna for PHP and there's something annoying.
As I push space, as I type a semicolon or a comma or a closing brace and other characters, it suggests me a list of variables `($_COOKIE, $_ENV, $_FILES...)`

In example this means that if I want to create a new function named test() and I type

```
function[space]test()[space]{[return]

the result is

function test()$_COOKIE {

}
```

to correctly create the function I have to type

```
function[space]test()[esc][space]{[return]
```

Is there a way to manage how Eclipse shows the autosuggestion?

Comment: I found out the problem, it was because of an Yii plugin.
I've uninstalled it and the problem is gone.